# Could not resolve :kotlin-native-prebuilt-linux-x86_64:1.8.10 in github actions pipeline

Tags: kotlin, gradle, github-actions, cicd, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to build KMM project in github actions on self-hosted linux runners.

On ./gradlew assembleRelease command starts, after sometime it throws the error below:

> :kmmmodule:detachedConfiguration3
> Could not resolve :kotlin-native-prebuilt-linux-x86_64:1.8.10.
> Required by:
> project :kmmmodule
> > Could not resolve :kotlin-native-prebuilt-linux-x86_64:1.8.10.
> > Could not get resource 'https://download.jetbrains.com/kotlin/native/builds/releases/1.8.10/linux-x86_64/kotlin-native-prebuilt-linux-x86_64-1.8.10.tar.gz'.
> 18 actionable tasks: 18 executed
> > Could not HEAD 'https://download.jetbrains.com/kotlin/native/builds/releases/1.8.10/linux-x86_64/kotlin-native-prebuilt-linux-x86_64-1.8.10.tar.gz'.
> > download.jetbrains.com

I tried with different version of gradle like 7.5,8.0,8.02... and kotlin 1.8.0,10,20 none worked.

Comment: Can you share a link to your reproducer project?

Comment: @gavr Looks like in self-hosted runners this link was blocked and now after unblocking its working.